# RadioGroupItem's description html string

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I am using DevExpress' RadioGroupItem and I need to send HTML text to its description.RadioGroupItem does not provide AllowHtmlString property.Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no embedded [HTML text formatting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4874) support for RadioGroupItem. Anyway you can track the following ticket in this regard: [RadioGroupItem provide the ability to use HTML text in the item's description](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S32827.aspx)